# Sonata Media: Change context programmatically

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm writing a little blog app where the user can publish public and private news. Users can attach files to these news. I have two contexts for this app: `public_news`, with files which can be accessed by everyone; and `private_news`, with files which can only be accessed if the user has log on.

I want to be able to move files from the public_news context to the private_news context when the user changes a news from public to private, and vice versa.

I was hoping to do something as simple as `$media->setContext('private_news');`, but this won't move the physical file from one directory to the other.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about recreating this media?

```
$oldMedia = getYourOldMedia();

// $media = clone($oldMedia); # For me it didn't work as expected
                              # YMMV - I didn't spend lots wondering about that
$media = new Media();

// This will work fine with image and file provider, 
// but it was not tested with other providers
$pool = $container->get('sonata.media.pool');
$provider = $pool->getProvider($oldMedia->getProviderName());
$media->setBinaryContent($provider->getReferenceFile($oldMedia));

}

$media->setProviderName($oldMedia->getProviderName());
$media->setContext('private_news');
/* copy any other data you're interested in */

$mediaManager->save($media);
$mediaManager->delete($oldMedia);
```

`$mediaManager->delete` might not delete your physical files depending on provider, you might want to create your own provider if you wish to do so.

#### Edit:

On further research I found out that you can manualy delete your files before deleting old media:

```
if ($pool->getFilesystem()->has($path)) {
    $pool->getFilesystem()->delete($path);
}
```

But don't do that before saving your new media entity.